# how to fix the maven build error on tez-dag stage?

Tags: maven, apache-tez

when I build the tez source code, the error occured on tez-dag stage(as the picture below). please tell me what happended and how to solve it?
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVW70.png)

Comment: Please show logs as text, not images. You can also read that text to see that it recommends you add extra options to the mvn command to get more useful output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `POM.xml` file related to the `tez-dag` dependency, you can see there is an execution of a `maven-antrun-plugin` plugin, with no version defined.

If your installed plugin version is prior to the 3.0.0 (as it can be seen in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)), your compilation will be fine. But if not, you have to replace the tag `<tasks>` by `<target>`, like this:

```
  ...
  <configuration>
    <target>
      <delete dir="${test.log.dir}" />
      <mkdir dir="${test.log.dir}" />
    </target>
  </configuration>
  ...
```

Comment: thank you, I just annotated the plugin because I found it's not needed